# Can “ap­pre­ci­ate” be used in this way?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, grammaticality, formality

(I am not a na­tive speaker.)

I just got an email re­gard­ing a failed or­der that used the fol­low­ing sen­tence:

> I **ap­pre­ci­ate** that this will not be what you wanted to hear and for that I apol­o­gize.

I un­der­stand what this sen­tence is try­ing to con­vey. But when you use *I ap­pre­ci­ate* in that or­der, it sounds like he is ap­pre­ci­at­ing that I am not sat­is­fied.

I just wanted to know whether you can use *ap­pre­ci­ate* like that, or whether who­ever wrote that sen­tence made a small mis­take.

Comment: "Appreciate" here means "understand". It's in the dictionary.

Comment: I actually never new that appreciate had two different meanings. It is kind of humorous to not know the second meaning and read that sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Appreciate* comes from the same Latin root as *appraise* and the original meaning of these words is "to determine the price of something". In essence, this word means that some object or situation is being studied with the goal of finding its true nature or value. In this sense it perfectly conveys the shopkeeper's sentiment: he has learned of the situation and presumably finds it troublesome. However, he should have included that he feels unsatisfied with the outcome of his *appraisal* if he chooses to use the verb in such a way. So perhaps you could say that he made a slight mistake.

Comment: That's really illuminating, thanks for the quick response.

Comment: No problems! It is quite an interesting usage of this word haha